# npm install the generator-jhipster 6.8.0 that is different with where from github

Tags: jhipster

when i use the [npm i generator-jhipster] to download the generator-jhipster, i found some different with where from github,such as [generators\server\templates\src\main\java\package\repository\PersistenceAuditEventRepository.java.ejs]

```
<%_ if (reactive) { _%>
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
<%_ } _%>

import java.time.Instant;
<%_ if (!reactive) { _%>
import java.util.List;
<%_ } _%>

/**
 * Spring Data <% if (databaseType === 'sql') { %>JPA<% } else if (databaseType === 'mongodb') { %>MongoDB<% } else if (databaseType === 'couchbase') { %>Couchbase<% } %> repository for the {@link PersistentAuditEvent} entity.
 */
```

here is the code where from githup

```
<%_ if (reactive) { _%>
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
<%_ } _%>

import java.time.Instant;
<%_ if (databaseType === 'sql' && reactive) { _%>
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.util.Map;
<%_ } _%>
<%_ if (!reactive) { _%>
import java.util.List;
<%_ } _%>

/**
 * Spring Data <% if (databaseType === 'sql' && !reactive) { %>JPA<% } else if (databaseType === 'sql' && reactive) { %>R2DBC<% } else if (databaseType === 'mongodb') { %>MongoDB<% } else if (databaseType === 'couchbase') { %>Couchbase<% } %> repository for the {@link PersistentAuditEvent} entity.
 */
```

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/repository/PersistenceAuditEventRepository.java.ejs

we can clearly see there has no judge about the  [(databaseType === 'sql' && reactive)] in code where from npm install.
Importantly， their package.json both are 6.8.0, i'm totally confuse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see in [GitHub](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster) doesn't have to match what you install, because on GitHub you see changes that have not been released yet.

In particular, version `6.8.0` was [released](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/releases/tag/v6.8.0) on *March 8, 2020* while the changes you mention were commited on *March 12, 2020* ([here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/commit/a8415d6fd9cbf9e63e16053d110470e40bd60547)), after version `6.8.0` was released.

The repository contains the most up-to-date changes, while a version release is a snapshot of the repo at certain date (considered to be stable).